# Simulation of Real Network with the help of User Mode Linux or Virtual Machines/Switch

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualenv, virtualhost

I am a beginner in User Mode Linux Area, and recently started working on it, by reading material available in Internet e.g; http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/source.html.

***My Objective*** :

Currently I am performing some tests, On  which I am using direct hardwares : e.g;
APs[Access Points]- Configured with different types of NAT [ Full Cone, Port Restricted,Symmetric etc] and Desktop's

Rather using such all hardwares Computers ,Desktops etc, I think I may use something like *User Mode Linux* which all together light-weight Linux's Virtual Instances, On that I can simulate my task e.g; Virtual Switch, Virtual light-weight Instances

I tried a lot by using several  Virtual Machines (VMWare) on same machine to Simulate different networks , and networks supposed to be connected Virtual Switch (didn'y find any).

**All together** -

[1]. Is there any one who has such past experience , Where you have simulated real network with the help of either Virtual Machines(UML or Virtual Box or VMWARE) and Virtual Switch (I don't know any).

[2]. If yes, Is it require too much effort ? means do you feel configurations are not much complex ?

Answer (score 3):

There is such a product.

It is called GNS3 VirtualBox Edition:
http://forum.gns3.net/topic3262.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used [vde](http://vde.sourceforge.net/) to simulate a network in the past. It's great and lets you setup things like virtual switches (http://wiki.virtualsquare.org/wiki/index.php/VDE). What I simulated were 5 virtual machines (using qemu) connceted to a virtual switch (using vde).

I'm not sure what the state of affairs is with virtualization products, but somethign like VMWare might also allow you to create a virtual network but I doubt it would be as flexible as VDE.

Comment: Thanks sashang @ Its great comments, I more looking into *Virtual Bridge* (Where I can customized NAT (Network Address Translation)) based on my use cases ? So I could connect various Virtual Instances together via Virtual Switch and each network conencted with other network via Virtual Bridge (with NAT functionality) or Virtual NAT router

Answer (score 1):

User Mode Linux is like very old, I would suggest using VDE as suggest by sashang, but simulating networks can he helpful.... However it's purely simulation, real devices in the real world can behave differently and vice verse....

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of open-source network simulators, which help automate the process of creating virtual machines and connecting them together, that you might find useful. I created a list of these tools, along with some tutorials, and posted it at: http://www.brianlinkletter.com/open-source-network-simulators.